# Timezone problem with jQuery.timeago plugin

Tags: jquery, timestamp, timeago

I am using timeago jQuery plugin for my blog, but there seems to be a problem with the timing itself, and I cant put my finger and what the cause of the problem is.

Its currently May 31st, 2011 02:30 local time here (GMT+DST). Now the example date I have used is... May 31st, 2011 02:01. The following tag for this would be

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-05-31T02:01:44+00:00">May 31st, 2011</abbr>
```

Yet the jQuery outputs that the date is "32 minutes from now", Its one hour ahead for some reason.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Hazarding a guess here so I might be quite wrong.*

The problem is that the test timesatmp you've specified has an offset of `0` so it's the same as UTC - but ***that's not the same as your time when following DST in the GMT timezone***.

GMT is the same as UTC i.e. the offset is `0`. However, you mention DST and when following Daylight Savings Time, your clock moves forward by 1 hour and so does your UTC offset. So your time right now, with respect to UTC, is actually `UTC + 0100`. That's where the extra hour is coming from.

It might help to convert all times to UTC first, after all, that's what it's for, right? `02:30 GMT` while following DST is `01:30 UTC`. So compared to this, the test timestamp of `02:01 UTC`, is about a half hour in the future - hence the `32 minutes from now`.

If you were expecting to see `30 minutes ago` instead, your test date should have been `2011-05-31T01:01:44+00:00` in order to express a UTC timestamp that was equivalent to the time of `02:01` *by your clock display*.

---

The safest solution would be to use UTC timestamps always - this is how SO, Facebook and Twitter date their posts. The UTC timestamp can then be unambiguously interpreted and formatted for each user's timezone.

Your job, then, would be to make sure the timestamp you use is not simply what you see on your clock face, but the UTC equivalent of it - in your current timezone, the UTC time could be 1 hour behind the time displayed. And depending on what you're using to generate your HTML, you should be able to find a function, built-into the language/platform or as a third-party library, that will give you the UTC equivalent of the current time displayed on your clocks in your timezone considering DST.

Comment: Your right, I've changed the time format to UTC and all seems fine. However now it means that I will have to publish posts as if they were posted one hour earlier.

Comment: @Ian If you do that all through the year, that would be incorrect - the problem is that you were using your clock time but publishing it as UTC. You have to do one of the following 1) Use the correct offset - so as long as DST is followed, your dates will have to have the offset of +01:00 2) Use actual UTC timestamps - this will be your time -01:00. I would recommend doing this - it will also work if you ever moved to a different timezone! This is how sites like SO, Facebook and Twitter date their posts - using actual UTC timestamps which are formatted for different users' timezones.

Comment: @mu is too short That sure would be nice - I've never understood the need for Daylight Savings!

Answer (score 0):

> Its currently May 31st, 2011 02:30
>   local time here (GMT+DST).

You don't say what the DST is, I will assume it's +1h, same as no.good.at.coding above

> Now the example date I have used is...
>   May 31st, 2011 02:01. The following
>   tag for this would be
>
> 2011-05-31T02:01:44+00:00

You are at **02:30** which is **01:30 UTC**. Your date is from **02:01 UTC** which is **03:01** your time, which then is half an hour in the future.

As suggested you should save all dates as UTC anyway. Python for example has a datetime.utcnow() method. Always save as UTC, then convert to the local timezone when displaying.